# Is there any way to show feedback for a form submission without Javascript?

Tags: html, forms

Let's say we have a basic HTML form like this:

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

When a user clicks on the Submit button, whatever is in the `action` attribute will happen without any javascript.

The question is, is there any way to show some kind of feedback based on the submission (either success or error) without javascript?
Also please note that the project is supposed to be hosted on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **no**

You need to have *some* kind of programming language involved.

Typically a form will submit to the URL specified in the action attribute and the response will be handled by server-side programming. GitHub Pages only supports static files so that isn’t an option unless you combine it with a third party host for your server-side code.

You can also handle the data using client-side programming. This requires JavaScript (although you can write in some other languages, such as TypeScript, that you can transpile to JavaScript). Typically you would add a submit event listener to the form.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought :/  To be clear, I'm just trying to handle a situation when there's [no javascript for whatever reason](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) but the form still gets submitted. So typescript is also no option for that. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

No. You must use some programming language.

However, if you're hosting the form,
Some hosts like Netlify will display a message once the message has been sent.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into Netlify to see how it goes. Don't they use JS to display the message though?

Comment: Great. If you're completely avoiding using any programming on your site, definitely look into static site hosts that provide form functions and validation.

Comment: I've just looked into Netlify forms and functions and I've seen a lot of Javascript. By the way, I'm not avoiding programming, I'm just trying to handle a situation when there's [no javascript for whatever reason](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) but the form still gets submitted...

Comment: I understand but you really don't need any Javascript really.  You just need to add "data-netlify= true" on your form. Check out this doc. It works great for me https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/

Comment: Does it work if you disable Javascript in your browser?